# Is it possible to add non-maven libraries to artifactory repository?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have java libraries which are not built as maven projects. Can I add the required libraries for the project into artifactory repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload them to your artifactory by deciding an appropriate groupId, artifactId and version. I would recommend to have a separate repository in Artifacts may be called `3rdParty` and upload such kind of artifacts into this repository. Configure Artifactory to use this if you access the public group in artifactory.

Comment: thank you for quick answer and advise on artifact mgmt